# grunt serve in Visual Studio 2015 linked to IE for debugging?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015, gruntjs

I inherited an `AngularJs` application that was built using **WebStorm, NodeJs, Npm, Grun**t etc.

The app is set up in such a way, that I have to run `grunt serve` to initialize a local server that hits the API and return data. If I simply run it as Localhost (through either WebStorm or VS), it does not pass validation to return my data through the API.

My question is; Is it possible to link `grunt serve` to IE in Visual Studio, in the same way you would run an application in ***Debugging (F5) mode***?

I enjoy using Visual Studio, and like debugging and stepping through my code with IE, as this allows me to set breakpoints in my JavaScript and C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not manage to link `"grunt serve"` to IE in Visual Studio, I was able to debug using IE, by running my project in Debug mode (F5).

I simply copied the path with token created when running `"grunt serve"`, and used this as my path in Local Host when debugging in Visual Studio. This way it connects to the API, and is validated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that Grunt Launcher will help you:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff